# the exact value of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\arcsin{\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n^2-1}}\right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Are there  methods to find the exact value of this infinite series ? :

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\arcsin{\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n^2-1}}\right)}$$

I have no idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 2}\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\right)&=&\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right)\\&=&\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\pi}{4},\end{eqnarray*}$$
but this telescopic trick does not apply to your series, and if we [look at the inverse symbolic calculator](http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=0.9057922&lookup_type=simple) we do not get anything promising.